# Login con php y kotlin que no avisa si he registrado usuario

Tags: php, android-studio, kotlin, login

estoy intentando hacer un login con php y android studio. En un principio, me funciona el código ya que tanto el email como el correo se guardan en la base de datos. El problema que me plantea, es que parece que el response no lee la respuesta del PHP, por lo tanto, no me avisa si el usuario esta creado ya en la base de datos o si ya existia en ella ( aunque si lo hace, me lo guarda o no lo creo,siguiendo el código del php, pero la cosa es que no me muestra el dialog alert).
He visto otras respuestas parecidas en esta página, pero no he logrado arreglarlo.

Gracias de antemano, y un saludo

```
    <?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
    
    require_once 'login.php';
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    // Verificar si el email ya existe en la base de datos
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usuario WHERE email = '".$email."'";
    $resultado = $conectar->query($query);
    $row = $resultado->fetch_row();
    $email_existente = $row[0] > 0;

    if ($email_existente) {
        echo "El email ya está registrado";
    } else {
        // Insertar el nuevo usuario en la base de datos
        $query = "INSERT INTO usuario (email, password) VALUES ('".$email."', '".$password."')";
        $resultado = $conectar->query($query);
        if ($resultado == true){
             echo "true";

        } else {
            echo  "algo está mal";
        }
    }
}


?>



private fun insertUser(email: String, password: String) {

        val url = "http://192.168.0.11/android_mysql/insertarDatos.php"
        val queue: RequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)

        val stringRequest: StringRequest = object : StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            Response.Listener<String> { response ->
                if (response == "true") {
                    AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Registrado")
                        .setMessage("El registro se ha realizado.")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK") { _, _ ->
                            startActivity(Intent(this, Login::class.java))
                        }
                        .show()
                } else if (response == "El email ya está registrado") {
                    AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Error")
                        .setMessage("Ya existe un usuario con ese correo.")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
                        .show()
                } else {
                    AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Error")
                        .setMessage("Ocurrió un error al registrar el usuario.")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
                        .show()
                }
            },


            Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                error.printStackTrace()
                AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Error")
                    .setMessage("Ocurrió un error de conexión.")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
                    .show()
            }) {

            override fun getParams(): MutableMap<String, String> {
                return hashMapOf("email" to email, "password" to password)
            }
        }

        queue.add(stringRequest)
    }





---

De momento, he usado un log para ver que respuesta me daba por el logcat. Parece que si que lo imprime y al registrar el usuario, recorre el segundo if del PHP e imprime el echo "Hecho". 
Pero aún no he conseguido que en el android studio lo reconozca. 
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3J7Qb.png
```

Comment: El problema es la comparación del valor de response, debido a que es una cadena, debes compararlo usando el método equals().

Answer (score 0):

El problema que estás enfrentando puede estar relacionado con cómo se está manejando la respuesta en el código de Android Studio. Parece que el código PHP está respondiendo correctamente con mensajes como "true" o "El email ya está registrado", pero no estás obteniendo la respuesta esperada en tu aplicación de Android.

Aquí hay algunas sugerencias para solucionar el problema:

Verifica la URL: Asegúrate de que la URL en tu código de Android Studio (http://192.168.0.11/android_mysql/insertarDatos.php) sea correcta y que esté apuntando al archivo PHP en tu servidor local.

Depuración en PHP: Agrega algunas declaraciones echo adicionales en tu código PHP para ayudar a identificar dónde puede estar ocurriendo el problema. Por ejemplo, puedes agregar un echo después de $email_existente = $row[0] > 0; para verificar si se está evaluando correctamente.

Depuración en Android Studio: Agrega algunas declaraciones de registro (logs) en tu código de Android Studio para verificar el valor de la respuesta que se recibe. Puedes utilizar Log.d(TAG, response) para imprimir la respuesta en la consola de registro (Logcat) y verificar si coincide con las respuestas esperadas.

Comparación de cadenas en Android Studio: En lugar de usar la comparación response == "true", considera utilizar response.trim().equals("true") para asegurarte de que no haya espacios adicionales alrededor de la respuesta. Lo mismo se aplica para las otras comparaciones de cadenas.

Revisa los permisos y la conexión a Internet: Asegúrate de que tu aplicación tenga los permisos necesarios para acceder a Internet en el archivo AndroidManifest.xml. Además, verifica que tu dispositivo o emulador tenga una conexión a Internet estable.

Al aplicar estas sugerencias y revisar tanto el código PHP como el de Android Studio, deberías poder identificar y solucionar el problema con la respuesta del servidor en tu aplicación Android.

Aquí tienes una versión modificada de tu código en Android Studio que implementa las sugerencias mencionadas anteriormente:

```
private fun insertUser(email: String, password: String) {
    val url = "http://192.168.0.11/android_mysql/insertarDatos.php"
    val queue: RequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)

    val stringRequest: StringRequest = object : StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
        Response.Listener<String> { response ->
            val trimmedResponse = response.trim()

            if (trimmedResponse == "true") {
                showAlertDialog("Registrado", "El registro se ha realizado.", true)
            } else if (trimmedResponse == "El email ya está registrado") {
                showAlertDialog("Error", "Ya existe un usuario con ese correo.", false)
            } else {
                showAlertDialog("Error", "Ocurrió un error al registrar el usuario.", false)
            }
        },
        Response.ErrorListener { error ->
            error.printStackTrace()
            showAlertDialog("Error", "Ocurrió un error de conexión.", false)
        }
    ) {
        override fun getParams(): MutableMap<String, String> {
            return hashMapOf("email" to email, "password" to password)
        }
    }

    queue.add(stringRequest)
}

private fun showAlertDialog(title: String, message: String, success: Boolean) {
    AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle(title)
        .setMessage(message)
        .setPositiveButton("OK") { _, _ ->
            if (success) {
                startActivity(Intent(this, Login::class.java))
            }
        }
        .show()
}
```

En este código, se han realizado las siguientes modificaciones:

Se agregó una función showAlertDialog para mostrar el cuadro de diálogo de manera más modular.
Se utilizó response.trim() para eliminar los espacios en blanco alrededor de la respuesta antes de realizar las comparaciones de cadenas.
Se modificaron las comparaciones de cadenas para utilizar trimmedResponse en lugar de response directamente.
Se llamó a la función showAlertDialog en lugar de repetir el código para mostrar el cuadro de diálogo en cada caso.
Espero que esto te ayude a solucionar el problema y a recibir correctamente la respuesta del servidor en tu aplicación Android. Recuerda también verificar los puntos adicionales mencionados anteriormente, como la URL correcta, los permisos de Internet y la conexión a Internet en tu dispositivo o emulador.

Comment: que significan los "_" , aquí : .setPositiveButton("OK") { _, _ -> ?

Comment: En el contexto que mencionas, el "_" se utiliza como un marcador para representar un parámetro o un valor que no es relevante o no se va a utilizar. Es una convención común en muchos lenguajes de programación.

Comment: Pero cuál es el contexto ahí, que valores se ponen ahí ya que me marca error.

Comment: Si estás experimentando un error al utilizar el "_", podría ser debido a un problema en otro lugar del código. Asegúrate de que el resto del código esté escrito correctamente y que los parámetros y valores se estén utilizando correctamente en el contexto específico donde se encuentran.

Comment: De momento, utilizando el log parece que el código si funciona, pero por alguna razón , en el if no es capaz de compararlo con el String.

Comment: Como esta respuesta viene puramente de ChatGPT, se debería borrarla: [está prohibido aquí](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5462).

Answer (score 0):

Aquí tienes un ejemplo corrigiendo el condicional if para comparar correctamente con un String:

```
print("Hola, para empezar escriba una palabra y siga las instrucciones")
palabra = input()

def vocales():
    vocal = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
    contador = 0
    for i in vocal:
        for j in palabra:
            if i == j:
                contador += 1
    return contador

print("Presione 1 si desea contar las letras o 2 si desea contar las vocales")
opcion = input()

if opcion.strip() == "1":
    print("El número de letras es:", len(palabra))
elif opcion.strip() == "2":
    contador_vocales = vocales()
    print("El número de vocales es:", contador_vocales)
else:
    print("Opción inválida")
```

En este ejemplo, se utiliza opcion.strip() para eliminar cualquier espacio en blanco alrededor del valor ingresado por el usuario antes de realizar la comparación con el String.

Comment: Revisar [answer], la respuesta debe ayudar a resolver la problemática planteada en la pregunta, evita agregar varias publicaciones como respuesta a la pregunta. Te sugerimos revisar también [CHATGPT está prohibido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/pol%c3%adtica-temporal-chatgpt-est%c3%a1-prohibido), saludo

Comment: Como esta respuesta viene puramente de ChatGPT, se debería borrarla: [está prohibido aquí](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5462).

Answer (score 0):

Si la petición es correcta y obtienes respuesta, el problema radica en la comparación, debes realizarla de esta manera  `if (trimmedResponse.equals("true")) {` , realiza el cambio en tu código:

```
 val stringRequest: StringRequest = object : StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
        Response.Listener<String> { response ->
            val trimmedResponse = response.trim()

            //*Error if (trimmedResponse == "true") {
            if (trimmedResponse.equals("true")) {
                showAlertDialog("Registrado", "El registro se ha realizado.", true)
            } else if (trimmedResponse == "El email ya está registrado") {
                showAlertDialog("Error", "Ya existe un usuario con ese correo.", false)
            } else {
                showAlertDialog("Error", "Ocurrió un error al registrar el usuario.", false)
            }
        },
        Response.ErrorListener { error ->
            error.printStackTrace()
            showAlertDialog("Error", "Ocurrió un error de conexión.", false)
        }
    ) {
        override fun getParams(): MutableMap<String, String> {
            return hashMapOf("email" to email, "password" to password)
        }
    }
```